# Display a message if the user tries to paste more than 2000 rows to an Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am using *Excel 2013* to create a workbook that will be filled by an enduser, honestly I have a lot of validations, so when the user is trying to paste more than 2000 rows it takes to much time.

My issue is not with the performance, I just want to display a `message box` if the user is trying to paste more than **2000 rows**. I looked for it in Google but couldn't find information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies this isn't the code for the answer, but it is an approach.

Basically this is going to be hard, as you have no easy way of telling when the user is about to paste data.  Getting the clipboard data isn't that hard, but intercepting the paste is.

To retrieve the clipboard data see the following MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194373.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

To intercept the paste, one idea would be to look into delayed rendering as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2437181/1285450) StackOverflow answer.

It might be easier to have a button 'Check Clipboard' that your users press before pasting?

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim sLastOp As String
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim a As Integer
 Dim Row As Range
  a = 0
 For Each Row In Range(Target.Cells.Address)
    If InStr(Row.Address, "A") Then
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next
 '--get the last operation from the undo stack
 sLastOp = Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).List(1)
 Select Case sLastOp
   '--if last operation was Paste or PasteSpecial, display message
   Case "Paste", "Paste Special"
   If a > 200 Then MsgBox "Please wait till pasting finishes." & a, vbOKOnly
   Case Else 'do nothing
 End Select
End Sub
```

Take this code and put it in a new sheet, it will work 100% on pasting and you can modify the message as you want.
But honestly if you are trying to delete more than 2000 rows an error will appear.
Another problem I could not to put this code to my sheet code I do not what is the problem it is not working.

Comment: posting solutions which don't even not work for you isn't a good idea, I don't see how it could help others. The main issue with your approach, that WorkSheet_Change event occurs AFTER paste is finished, so user will get this message after waiting, not before.

Comment: Dear Máté Juhász, it is my fault to put it as an answer i should put it as a comment ,Apologies i am new to stack over flow .. but know i am trying to make it works with my code

Comment: how does getting the last op from the undo stack help?  surely if its on that stack its already too late.